# Using Passive Voice in This Sentence

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Just a minute ago, when I look at worldometers and I saw a sentence:

> COVID-19 forecasting model **used** by the US Government.

I can't understand that part of the sentence: used by the US Government. 
So why don't use the part so: **is used** by the US Government.
I can't understand it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [full sentence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/) is

> 134,475 deaths by August 4 (total cumulative count, with uncertainty range from 95,092 to 242,890 deaths) now projected in the USA by the Dr. Murray and researchers in Washington state COVID-19 forecasting model used by the US Government.

"used by the US Government" isn't an independent clause, so it does not need "is". Perhaps the reason why is clearer if you omit some of the other content:

> 134,475 deaths [are] now projected in the USA by the model used by the US Government

I do think the sentence is missing a finite verb (the [are]), but this could be a case of [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Comment: I would also say the existence of ***the*** *Dr. Murray* is wrong, and the article should be moved to where one is actually missing. In short:  *… by [] Dr. Murray and researchers in Washington state **in the** COVID-19 forecasting model used by the US Government*.